# Get jQuery UI Slider value when sliding?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, youtube-api

I have this demo where you can change the time and volume of a YouTube video with the YouTube Player API. What I'm trying to do it update the UI slider value when sliding or "scrubbing" the slider. I have already achieved the first part which was lively updating the value when sliding using this neat little snippet of code:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#content").text("video_time: " + ui.value.toString().toHHMMSS());
}
```

Unfortunately... with what I'm trying to do, the time updates successfully when I'm sliding, but resets after a second. This is because I have a present function that is causing it to constantly update and make sure that the jQuery UI Slider value matches up with that of the YouTube video, to getting this to work is sort of a challenge for me.

Please let me know if there is any possible work-around for this to work, thanks!

**DEMO:** http://codepen.io/mistkaes/pen/MwONzK?editors=001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

> $("#content").text("video_time: " + player.getCurrentTime().toString().toHHMMSS());

line in your `onReady` event is overwriting the one in your `slide` event. Since you pause the video when you start to seek, I just check if the player is paused in `onReady`, and if it isn't, use the player's current time as the value.

In other words, change

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#content").text("video_time: " + 
    player.getCurrentTime().toString().toHHMMSS());
}, 250);
```

to

```
setInterval(function() {
    if(player.getPlayerState()!=2)//video not paused, use player time as video_time
    //thus, when the player IS paused, use the value from the slider as the 
    //video time, which is what you wanted
    {
        $("#content").text("video_time: " + 
        player.getCurrentTime().toString().toHHMMSS());
    }
}, 250);
```

in your `onReady` event.

Comment: I used [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status) documentation to find the number that corresponds to the player being paused.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!